# I have a list of keywords and want to count the number of match keywords in each cells text from EXCEL File

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 sheet in a excel file. one is a Dictionary sheet and 2nd is a sheet containing a column of text. I want to match the dictionary keywords columns one by one and then the number of match keywords counts in each cell of the text column.

I have tried these formulas:
=(LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,Sheet1!A:A,"")))/LEN(Sheet1!A:A)
in this B2 is the first (start) cell of the text column and Sheet1!A:A is the dictionary column of other sheet.
but by this i get zero as a result

=(LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,Sheet1!A:A,"")))/LEN(Sheet1!A:A)

The result will be **like this:**

```
         Text                      number_of_keyword_match    | number_of_keyword_match using DIC col 2 |  ........
                                        using DIC col 1

1 any Text or sentence/sentences          e.g match "3"             
2                                                    7              
3                                                    0              
4                                                    15             
5    .................................................                                   
7 .....................................................
.......................................................
..................................continue up to 2815 rows....
```

Comment: Expected inputs and output aren't entirely clear. I've tried answering what I assumed was your meaning, but please elaborate on in- and outputs if you meant something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider countif(), as an example:

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet2!A1:A10,Sheet1!A1)
```

which assumes your list starts in cell A1 on sheet1 and your text in cell a1 on sheet2.

[image]

To drag the formula as I showed it, without the data range moving you need :

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet2!A$1:A$10,Sheet1!A1)
```

if you put $ before the letters, then the columns don't move.

Comment: This only works if OP is counting exact cell contents instead of word occurrences within a larger text, but you're right, his question doesn't explicitly state either

Comment: @HarmteMolder I did this as an example as I mentioned in the first line.What the OP wants is not really clear, TBH, I don't really follow the "results"... But between us we have given tools that the OP can take further. Plus 1 for yours though - I think you are closer than I.

Comment: @SolarMike Your answer is right but its not work well ,
I also used this formula
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Dictionary!A2:A307,B2)))
its work good 
but a one problem is that it increament by 1 in start and in the end in Dictionary range ,with every next cell 
Dictionary!A3:A308 then 
Dictionary!A4:A309 i don't want this ,
I want this rang in all the cell like this Dictionary!A2:A307

Comment: @SolarMike Your answer is right but its not work well ,
I also used this formula
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Dictionary!A2:A307,B2)))
its work good 
but a one problem is that it increament by 1 in start and in the end in Dictionary range ,with every next cell 
Dictionary!A3:A308 then 
Dictionary!A4:A309 i don't want this ,
I want the range in all the cell like this " Dictionary!A2: A307"

Comment: @HarmteMolder
I like your answer and you correctly understand my problem i 100% want this but  its not work give an formula error 
now I also used this formula
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Dictionary!A2:A307,B2)))
its work good 
but a one problem is that it increament by 1 in start and in the end in Dictionary range ,with every next cell like this 
Dictionary!A3:A308 then 
Dictionary!A4:A309 i don't want this ,
I want the range in all the cell like this " Dictionary!A2: A307"

Comment: @csit to stop it incrementing when you drag down, try Dictionary!A$2:A$307,B2)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your text input looks like this:

```
 |          A           |
-+----------------------+
1|apple apple beat beat |
2|apple beat beat carrot|
3|carrot apple apple    |
```

and your dictionary looks like this:

```
 |   A   |   B   |
-+-------+-------+
1|apple  |beat   |
2|beat   |carrot |
3|       |       |
```

This formula will give you the count per word per cell of text

```
=(LEN(text!A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(text!A1,dictionary!A1,"")))/LEN(dictionary!A1)
```

(In this example `2`)

If I understand correctly, your expected output would be extra columns in the `text` sheet where each cell contains the sum of counts of each word in the corresponding column in `dictionary`, right? For example:

```
 |          A           | B | C |
-+----------------------+---+---+
1|apple apple beat beat | 4 | 2 |
2|apple beat beat carrot| 3 | 3 |
3|carrot apple apple    | 2 | 1 |
```

You can use [array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-array-formula-E43E12E0-AFC6-4A12-BC7F-48361075954D) to do this, starting with this one in cell B1:

```
=SUM(IFERROR((LEN(text!$A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(text!$A1;dictionary!A:A;"")))/LEN(dictionary!A:A);0))
```

But instead of pressing `Enter` after pasting it in, press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` to run it as an array formula. Then drag this formula down and to the right to get all the counts you want.